# Getting ufunc 'true_divide' although both variables have datatype object

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
a = sum(df1['P']*df1['Q'])
b=sum(df1['Q'])
c = a/b

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' cannot use operands with types dtype('float64') and dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

Here I am getting an error although the datatypes of both P and Q is object.

Comment: In pandas, object dtype means the elements can be anything.  The real question is what's `a` and `b`?  What has the * and `sum` done to those objects?  The error tell us that `a` (or at least on element of `a` is a float, but the corresponding element of `b` is a datetime64.  My guess is that `df1['Q']` contains dates.

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `jupyter-notebook` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for responding.Yes Q contains dates and it is resolved.